# How many DIY recipes are there for "Bunny Day"?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

With the advent of the new month, I found a long-eared ne'er-do-well lurking along my beach, who *claimed* to not be wearing a costume. What's more, the scoundrel admitted to vandalizing my island -- stuffing it to the gills with, of all things, *eggs*.

Before vanishing (alongside what I can only presume to be a malevolent cackle), he taunted me, claiming that he would be back on **April 12th** -- Bunny Day -- and challenged me to craft all of the DIY recipes he had hidden around the island.

Assuming we take this stranger at his word, how many DIY recipes are we talking about? He may be shifty, but he *did* mention a reward...

Comment: Check from [here](https://game8.co/games/Animal-Crossing-New-Horizons/archives/285168)

Comment: So that's 36 then? Or maybe only 18? Apparently clothing doesn't count.

Comment: I’m pretty sure Tom Nook is in the  costume.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the bunny's reward, there are 17 main recipes to collect:

- Bunny Day Bag
- Bunny Day Bed
- Bunny Day Crown
- Bunny Day Fence
- Bunny Day Festive Balloons
- Bunny Day Flooring
- Bunny Day Glowy Garland
- Bunny Day Lamp
- Bunny Day Merry Balloons
- Bunny Day Rug
- Bunny Day Stool
- Bunny Day Table
- Bunny Day Vanity
- Bunny Day Wall
- Bunny Day Wall Clock
- Bunny Day Wardrobe
- Bunny Day Wreath

And there is indeed a reward for crafting all of them:

> The Wobbling Zipper Toy, Bunny Day Arch, and the Bunny Day Wand

On the last day of the event, you can also get the Bunny Day Basket from Zipper (not required for the reward).

Additionally, there are a bunch of other wearables unrelated to the bunny's reward, obtained by collecting their corresponding eggs:

- Earth-Egg Outfit
- Earth-Egg Shell
- Earth-Egg Shoes
- Leaf-Egg Outfit
- Leaf-Egg Shell
- Leaf-Egg Shoes
- Sky-Egg Outfit
- Sky-Egg Shell
- Sky-Egg Shoes
- Stone-Egg Outfit
- Stone-Egg Shell
- Stone-Egg Shoes
- Water-Egg Outfit
- Water-Egg Shell
- Water-Egg Shoes
- Wood-Egg Outfit
- Wood-Egg Shell
- Wood-Egg Shoes

For collecting all of the egg wearables DIY recipes, you'll receive recipes for:

- Egg Party Dress
- Egg Party Hat

I count 41 recipes in total.

Comment: I *believe* the Bunny Day Arch isn't required, because I've got the other 17 + 20 recipes, and I've started getting "repeat" recipes in the Bunny Day DIY Bottles.

Comment: Thanks for the complete list and including the spoiler tab! +1, not sure why this doesn't have more votes